# How to Click link in phpunit testing with Symfony 2

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I am new in PHPUnit Testing with Symfony 2.

I am trying to click a link to and test whether its redirects to the page which contains some text.
My code is :

```
$client = static::createClient();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/Site'); 

$link = $crawler->filter('a:contains("Click for Report")')->eq(1)->link(); 

$crawler->$client->click($link);

$this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

$this->assertContains('Detail Report',$client->getResponse()->getContent());
```

Every time I run this test an error says: "InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty."
on the code >>

```
$link = $crawler->filter('a:contains("Detail Report")')->eq(1)->link();
```

I don't know why the node is empty.

Any help will be highly Appreciated !
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the status response before do any other check, so move the line `$this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());` before the node filter operation. If the response is good, investigate in the client response and see what appen with `die(var_dump( $client->getResponse()->getContent() ))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: this is not unit-testing – this is a functional test.

Regarding your test: theoretically, it should work, but without the HTML, it’s difficult to say where’s the problem. Chances are it’s simply the `eq(1)`, as the argument to `eq()` is 0-based, not 1-based, so you are selecting the 2nd link that contains “Click for Report”, and maybe there is only 1 such link on the page.

BTW, getting the link like this is simpler and more readable:

`$crawler->selectLink('Click for Report')->link()`